# ReactJS как изменить state на событие onClick?

Tags: reactjs, state

```
class Article extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      visible: false
    };
  }
  updateVisible() {
    this.setState({visible: true});
  }
  render() {
    let author = this.props.data.author;
    let text = this.props.data.text;
    let bigtext = this.props.data.bigtext;
    let visible = this.state.visible;
    return (
      <div className="article">
        <p className="card__author">{author}</p>
        <p className="card__text">{text}</p>
        <a href="#" className={"card__readmore " + (visible ? 'none' : '')} onClick={this.updateVisible}>Подробнее</a>
        <p className={"card__big-text " + (visible ? '' : 'none')}>{bigtext}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Попробовал так, но выдает ошибку

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
    visible: false
  };

  this.updateVisible = this.updateVisible.bind(this);
}
```